# What are the rules allowing to write a template class with an optionnal trait typedef like pointer in a unique_ptr deleter

Tags: templates, template-specialization, unique-ptr, enable-if

The way *unique_ptr* manage an optional `typedef foo_type pointer;` in a deleter surprised me. I looked the visual studio 2012 implementation and i strip a small implementation for the example :

```
// this helper defined a type named Type as Traits::Type if it exists
// otherelse it is defined as Implicit
template < class Implicit, class Traits >
class ResolveType {
    class WrapInt {
    public:
        WrapInt( int );
    };

    template < class T >
    static auto MyFn( int ) -> typename T::Type;

    template < class T >
    static auto MyFn( WrapInt ) -> Implicit;

public:
    typedef decltype( MyFn<Traits>(0) ) Type;
};
```

Now, if we are able to write this :
    struct A {
    typedef unsigned int Type;
    };
    struct B {
    };

```
typedef ResolveType< int, A >::Type ResultA; // this will resolve to unsigned int
typedef ResolveType< int, B >::Type ResultB; // this will resolve to int
```

What is surprising is the ill formed `MyFn` in the case we use B inside `ResolveType` because `typename B::Type` does not exist.

So i have three questions :
1. Is this a standard behavior or a non standard trick working fine only in the visual studio compiler ?
2. If this is the correct standard behavior, what are the rules behind that black magic ?
3. Does this is in relation with *enable_if*, because i have some difficulties too to understand the logic on how it allow rejection of function overload, a bit in the same way the example above by invaliding the signature ?

Thanks.

Comment: I should had search a little bit more before asking, i found my answer : *SFINAE*

Comment: +1 "What is surprising is the ill formed MyFn in the case we use B ... because typename B::Type does not exist".